# Jquery toolTip get from HiddenField?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have asp.net calendar I embedded asp.net  HiddenField controller and I put the message value attributed just I want to ask how can I use  HiddenField  value for JQ tooltip

```
$("#hf_taskID_cal").tooltip($("#hf_taskID_cal").val());
```

Error

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'TaskID:10047   Start Date:2/25/2013 12:00:00 AM    End Date:2/26/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: see the update Uncaught Error

Comment: Looks like you don't use the right way to initialize your plugin. Have you checked the documentation? What is the exact plugin you are using? There is a lot of information missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 $("#Calendar1 td").has("#ClassPerentORchilld").tooltip({ content: $("#hf_taskID_cal").val() })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your element properly via jQuery using `$`

```
$("#hf_taskID_cal").tooltip($('#hf_taskID_cal').val());
```